# Android MediaPlayer does not play after restoring app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

In my app there are several short (less than one second) sounds. So MediaPlayer finishes in PlaybackComplete state according to the diagram ( https://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif ).

I would like to play the sound again. It works fine till several-time minimalization and restoring app - then there is no sound and in logCat, I can see errors:

```
    start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x90279300)
    E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
    E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

in top of activities class is media player defined (all sounds) like this:

```
private  MediaPlayer mpStart;
```

and in onCreate:

```
mpStart = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gong);
```

and sound is played with:

```
mpStart.start();
```

in some other functions...

Because of the fact that problems occure during minimalizing app, I have tried add again in onResume

```
mpStart = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gong);
```

but it not helped.

I have tested to add before start
mpStart.pause() or stop() and prepare(), but problem is still there.

I'm using API 23

Answer (score 0):

The fact is you're not stopping the mediaplayer at any point.

Inside your click listener structure your code as

1.stopPlaying();
2.mpStart = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, (your audio raw file here);
3.mpStart.start();

Below is the stopPlaying() function.

```
private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mpStart!= null) {
        mpStart.stop();
        mpStart.release();
        mpStart= null;
       }
     }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for Narendra_Naths reply.
I am not sure If I understand well. You sugest, that I should run stop(), release() and create() before each start().

Comment: Yes. It's not the best way to do it but it will keep your mediaplayer from freezing.

Answer (score 0):

So I have changed each start() to:

```
if (mpStop != null) {
                mpStop.stop();
                mpStop.release();
                mpStop = null;
}
mpStop = MediaPlayer.create(kontext, R.raw.zvukovy_signal_konec);
mpStop.start();
```

And I have quite heavily tested app with minimalizing and aganin restoring and unfortunately after some time it stops again play sounds.

here is a bit longer log with several attempts of playing sound:

```
2021-04-13 20:10:40.008 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:40.010 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: Pid:17042 MediaPlayer destructor
2021-04-13 20:10:40.017 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(65, 158552, 17607)
2021-04-13 20:10:40.029 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake true uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:40.029 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: Pid:17042 MediaPlayer::start
2021-04-13 20:10:40.032 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
2021-04-13 20:10:40.054 17042-17055/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink W/HwMediaMonitorManager: HwMediaMonitorService not published, waiting...
2021-04-13 20:10:40.055 17042-17055/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/HwMediaMonitorManager: The HwMediaMonitorService is NULL, write exception Log failed(long mode)! eventId(916010106), eventLevel(3), subType(1)
2021-04-13 20:10:40.055 17042-17055/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
2021-04-13 20:10:40.055 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
2021-04-13 20:10:40.055 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:43.036 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:43.037 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8f6e0480)
2021-04-13 20:10:43.037 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
2021-04-13 20:10:43.038 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:43.040 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: Pid:17042 MediaPlayer destructor
2021-04-13 20:10:43.046 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(65, 694412, 2288)
2021-04-13 20:10:43.059 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake true uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:43.060 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: Pid:17042 MediaPlayer::start
2021-04-13 20:10:43.062 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
2021-04-13 20:10:43.085 17042-17055/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink W/HwMediaMonitorManager: HwMediaMonitorService not published, waiting...
2021-04-13 20:10:43.085 17042-17055/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/HwMediaMonitorManager: The HwMediaMonitorService is NULL, write exception Log failed(long mode)! eventId(916010106), eventLevel(3), subType(1)
2021-04-13 20:10:43.085 17042-17055/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
2021-04-13 20:10:43.086 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
2021-04-13 20:10:43.086 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:44.062 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:44.062 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8f6e0480)
2021-04-13 20:10:44.062 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
2021-04-13 20:10:44.063 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake false uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:44.065 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: Pid:17042 MediaPlayer destructor
2021-04-13 20:10:44.071 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(65, 694412, 2288)
2021-04-13 20:10:44.085 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: [HSM] stayAwake true uid: 10098, pid: 17042
2021-04-13 20:10:44.086 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink I/MediaPlayer: Pid:17042 MediaPlayer::start
2021-04-13 20:10:44.088 17042-17042/com.fiksoftware.flexibilnitrenink W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

Please where could be some problem?

Comment: kontext is in clas deffined: Context kontext; and then in onCreate kontext = this;